# An unusually large number of review tasks recently. What happened (if anything)?

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close

I frequently check the review queues here, and I almost always do not get the opportunity to review anything because someone else has already cleared up the queue (a good sign for this community!).

Today I was surprised, not only because reviews were available for me in two different categories, but we had ***seven*** closure reviews available!

We have only had 455 closure reviews done in total (an usually several people will do a review for the same closure, the number of questions for which closure has been reviewed is expected to be significantly smaller than that), and we got 7 today alone:

[image]

I am just curious to know what happened? Does it have something to do with the election going on (e.g. someone decided to significantly raise their participation level and went through ***a lot*** of questions and vote to close some of them along the way)?

I'm not saying that the surge in close votes was a bad idea: in fact I voted to close some of those questions, especially the ones that "need more focus" since the asker was trying to ask several questions at once; so I actually think that whoever cast those initial close votes was doing a decent job. I'm just curious what happened (or if this was all just a coincidence!) because this observation was a bit unusual!

P.S. I think TheSimpliFire takes care of most reviews fairly quickly, when its a "First Question" or "First Answer" or "Suggested Edit" review, for example, but would avoid voting on a closure because when a diamond moderator votes on a closure the democratic process for that closure ends. Therefore I understand that we probably wouldn't have had 7 close reviews available today if TheSimpliFire voted on them, but why did we have so many in the first place?